# How to get updated value from state?

Tags: reactjs

I need some help with this code:

```js
const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    userApi.checkAuth().then((res) => {
      if (res.message === "ok") {
        setIsAuth(true);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
```

I send a request to the server to check if the user has a token, and depending on the response, I want to change the value of the state. The state changes its value, but I can't get the last value from the state. I've tried this:

```js
setIsAuth((prevState) => !prevState);
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: In the dependency array of the `useEffect` you should add `[isAuth]`

Comment: *How to get updated value from state* - you have the updated value in the next render ..

Comment: Isn't this going to navigate to `/login` every time because the first render will occur before your API response resolves?

Comment: ☝️ this tbh ...

Comment: @rantao thanks for hint, I'll try to use useLayoutEffect hook.

Comment: Another option would be to initialize `isAuth` to `true`. Then do `setIsAuth(res.message === "ok")` in your effect. This would allow the user to see the `<Outlet/>` on first render; then once the response resolves, those with an unsuccessful auth check would be redirected. Only downside is unauthenticated user's would see a flash of the authenticated page, but I think that's inevitable anyways with client-side auth